# What is going wrong when making my adjacency matrix in C?

Tags: c, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to take an input file with the structure of this:

```
10
4 8 10 
9 6 10 7 2
1 6 2 3 7
7 2 9 1 5
3 6 1 5
8 5 4 
5 3 8 7 
6 1 3 9 
2 7 1 9
10 4 9
```

Where the first line is the number of vertices and the next lines are the vertex and all vertexes adjacent to that vertex. I have written some code for this too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



struct node
{
    int vertex;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* createNode(int);

struct Graph
{
    int numVertices;
    struct node** adjLists;
};

struct Graph* createGraph(int vertices);
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest);
void printGraph(struct Graph* graph);

struct node* createNode(int v)
{
    struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->vertex = v;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct Graph* createGraph(int vertices)
{
    struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->numVertices = vertices;

    graph->adjLists = malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node*));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
        graph->adjLists[i] = NULL;

    return graph;
}

void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest)
{
    // Add edge from src to dest
    struct node* newNode = createNode(dest);
    newNode->next = graph->adjLists[src];
    graph->adjLists[src] = newNode;

    // Add edge from dest to src
    newNode = createNode(src);
    newNode->next = graph->adjLists[dest];
    graph->adjLists[dest] = newNode;
}

void printGraph(struct Graph* graph)
{
    int v;
    for (v = 0; v < graph->numVertices; v++)
    {
        struct node* temp = graph->adjLists[v];
        printf("\n Adjacency list of vertex %d\n ", v);
        while (temp)
        {
            printf("%d -> ", temp->vertex);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{

   char c[1000];
   FILE *fptr;


  if ((fptr = fopen("/Users/n/Documents/cis/small_graph.txt", "r")) == NULL)
  {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);         
  }

   fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]",c);
   printf("\n %s",c);

   int no_vertices = atoi(c);

   struct Graph* graph =createGraph(no_vertices);

   const size_t line_size = 300;
   char* line = malloc(line_size);

   for(int i = 0; i<=no_vertices; i++){
        //fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]",c);
        //printf("\n %s", c);

        fgets(line, line_size, fptr);
        printf(line);
        char* token = strtok(line, " ");
        int start_vertex = atoi(token);
        while (token){
            printf("token: %s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL,  " ");
            if(token != NULL){
                int dest_vertex = atoi(token);
                addEdge(graph, start_vertex-1, dest_vertex-1);
            }
            //int dest_vertex = atoi(token);
            //addEdge(graph, start_vertext, dest_vertex);

        }
        //printf(line);

   }



   printGraph(graph);
   return 0;
}
```

However, my output for this, when calling printGraph, is not the same as the sample file:

```
Adjacency list of vertex 0
 1 -> 5 -> 2 -> 6 -> 6 -> 2 -> 1 -> 5 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 1
 8 -> 0 -> 6 -> 6 -> 0 -> 8 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 2
 5 -> 4 -> 4 -> 0 -> 5 -> 0 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 3
 9 -> 7 -> -1 -> 9 -> 7 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 4
 -1 -> 6 -> 7 -> 2 -> 7 -> 2 -> 6 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 5
 -1 -> 8 -> 2 -> 0 -> 2 -> 0 -> 8 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 6
 1 -> 4 -> 4 -> 0 -> 8 -> 1 -> 0 -> 8 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 7
 4 -> -1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 3 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 8
 9 -> 1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 1 -> 6 -> 9 -> 5 -> 

 Adjacency list of vertex 9
 8 -> 3 -> 8 -> 3 ->
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting 0's in the printGraph output, and how to get rid of the empty vertex?

Thanks

Comment: Don't mix `fscanf` with `fgets`. Use one or the other. And regardless of which one you decide to use, always check the return value. `fscanf` returns the number of items successfully converted. `fgets` returns a non-NULL pointer if it's successful.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i<=no_vertices; i++){` <<-- `for(int i = 0; i < no_vertices; i++){`